# dynamically create check box and insert its text to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying To create check boxes list dynamically using c# and insert the check box text values to databse.But I dnt Understand How Can I Create and access its values to insert into db.Is there any one help me in this regard coz i have no strong idea except this.

```
public void CreateCheckBox(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(@"<input type=""checkbox"" name=""link"" value=" + "CA0" + i +">"+"CA0"+ i +"<br>") ;
    }
}
```

How Can I access its value to be inserted to db.Plz Help

Comment: can you add more code, and let us know in what server/client framework you are working with?

Comment: I have Nothing Beside this Just Calling This Method On page Load and here is out put http://dnet.sml.com.pk:85/Au_new.aspx

Comment: I would reccomend going through some asp.net tutorials, to save values you need to handle the postback from the page http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/ http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_quick_guide.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can assign an id attribute to the checkboxes like:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        Response.Write(@"<input id='check'" + i.ToString() + " type=""checkbox"" name=""link"" value=" + "CA0" + i +">"+"CA0"+ i +"<br>") ;
    }
```

then on the event that you want to retrieve the values simply you can use the following:

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
    var data=Request.Form["check" + i.ToString()]; // this should hold the value of the checkbox as string
}
```

hope that it will help

regards

Comment: I am getting error on this error `CS1026: ) expected` on this line `Response.Write(@"<input id='check'" + i.ToString() + " type=""checkbox"" name=""link"" value=" + "CA0" + i +">"+"CA0"+ i +"<br>") ;`

Comment: how can i check in second method that wether check box is checked or not